# Moving code into a factory in an Angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to clean up a controller that has too many lines of code in it. In the controller below where you find a function called getProductDetails, I would like to move the filter to a factory or a service, but I am not sure how to do it.

```
'use strict';

(function () {
var userQuoteBuild = angular.module('priceApp');
userQuoteBuild.controller('quoteBuilderController', function ($scope, $http) {

// loads of controller logic here...

    $scope.getProductDetails = function (item) {

        $scope.listOfProductVariants = item.default_variant_attributes;

        // TODO: put this in its own factory?
        $scope.selectedProductAttributes = $scope.listOfAttributes.filter(function (item) {
            var validated = false, i, length = $scope.listOfProductVariants.length;
            for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (item.name === $scope.listOfProductVariants[i]){
                    validated = true;
                }
            }
            return validated;
        });
    };



});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('priceApp')
        .factory('filterService', filterService);

    function filterService() {
        var service = {
            getValidated: getValidated
        }

        return service;

        function getValidated(list, variants) {
            return list.filter(function (item) {
                var validated = false, i, length = variants.length;
                for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    if (item.name === variants[i]) {
                        validated = true;
                    }
                }
                return validated;
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

Simply inject this `filterService` to your controller and then use it as in example here:

```
     $scope.selectedProductAttributes = filterService
                                           .getValidated($scope.listOfAttributes,
                                                         $scope.listOfProductVariants)
```

I followed [John Papa's AngularJS Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide). Make sure to choose a better name than `filterService`. : )

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
userQuoteBuild.factory('myService', function() {
    var service = {
        getProductDetails: function(item) {
            // your logic
            return value;
        }
    }
    return service;
});
```